# NullPointerException accessing a Neo4J database in a Singleton

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, neo4j

I'm working on a Neo4J database, using it in a little social network. The idea is:
As a user, you connect to the website, and it connects you to a N4J db.
I tried to avoid problem related to multiple instances of the db by creating it through a Singleton. However, I think my users must be able to "connect" and "disconnect", so I created method for that, but when I use disconnect() on a user, the others run through a NullPointerException due to the fact that they can't access the db anymore (which I thought was handled by the Singleton).

Here is the code, which I believe will make things clearer :

The main that I use to test my code :

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

        Node root;
        N4JAdmin admin = new N4JAdmin();

        Transaction tx = GraphDB.getGraphDb().beginTx();
        try {
            root = GraphDB.getGraphDb().createNode();
            root.setProperty("Nom", "aname");
            root.setProperty("Prenom", "afirstname");
            tx.success();
        } finally {
            tx.finish();
        }

        N4JUser sr = admin.addUser("Ribeiro", "Swen", 1);
        //14 more addUser, it creates nodes in the db with the 3 properties, works fine


//      The following connect() calls are commented because the errors occurs with or without them

//      sr.connect();
//      the 14 others...

        sr.addAcquaintance(cw.getUserNode());
        sr.addAcquaintance(fc.getUserNode());

        sr.disconnect();
        System.out.println("+++++++++ sr disconnected ++++++++++");

        bm.addAcquaintance(cm.getUserNode());
// and more operations...

        GraphDB.getGraphDb().shutdown();
    }
```

the addAquaintance code :

```
 public void addAcquaintance(Node target) {
            Transaction tx = GraphDB.getGraphDb().beginTx();
            try {           
                this.userNode.createRelationshipTo(target, RelTypes.CONNAIT);
                System.out.println(this.userNode.getProperty("Nom")+" "+this.userNode.getProperty("Prenom")+" est maintenant ami avec : "+ target.getProperty("Nom")+" "+target.getProperty("Prenom"));
                tx.success();
            } finally {
                tx.finish();
            }
        }
```

And the GraphDB class, which is my Singleton :

```
public final class GraphDB {

    private static final String DB_PATH = "/Workties/database/workties.db";
    private static GraphDatabaseService graphDb;
    private static boolean instanciated = false;

    private GraphDB(){
        GraphDB.graphDb = new GraphDatabaseFactory().newEmbeddedDatabase(DB_PATH);
        registerShutdownHook(graphDb);
        GraphDB.instanciated = true;
    }

    private static void registerShutdownHook( final GraphDatabaseService graphDb ){
        Runtime.getRuntime().addShutdownHook( new Thread(){
            @Override
            public void run(){
                graphDb.shutdown();
            }
        } );
    }

    public static GraphDatabaseService getGraphDb(){
        if (!GraphDB.instanciated) {
            new GraphDB();
            System.out.println("New connection : " +GraphDB.graphDb.toString());
        }
        return GraphDB.graphDb; 
    }
}
```

Note : the instanciated attribute was added later, but even without it it didn't work.

My problem comes from the fact that I thought this type of error wouldn't happen using a Singleton, so I'm a bit stuck...

Thanks in advance for your help !

EDIT : the disconnect method :

```
public void disconnect(){
        GraphDB.getGraphDb().shutdown();
    }
```

Comment: What does the disconnect method do? Can you share that as well?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should not have to call shutdown for every user- once the DB is instantiated for the first time, it is enough to last you for all your querying etc. Why do you want to connect and disconnect?

The nullpointer is because shutdown shuts down Neo4j but your singleton still thinks instanciated=true, so it returns a handle to a graphDb that isn't really there. Even without the instanciated variable which you added, the singleton maintains a reference to graphDb after it's shutdown. 
Strongly advise against doing the shutdown at all unless your app is terminating.

Comment: Thanks for these explanations. Well, the users don't really have to connect and disconnect, but then I don't really see where to call shutdown apart from the registershutdownhook method, which is called in a very specific situation. The thing is, this website is a school project, so I give the .war to my teacher and he tests it, so I wanna make sure there is no problem accessing the db in any way because I am not alone on this one.

Comment: That's fine, you won't shut it down until your web container terminates. You can add a servlet context listener and call shutdown when destroy is invoked